# Executing one function while waiting on another synchronouse function to complete

Tags: c#, azureservicebus

I have the following use case:

When I dequeue a message from an Azure Service Bus queue, sometimes the time needed to complete the message is long (5-10 minutes). I need to be able to renew the lock on the message, as the default time allowed for processing is 60 seconds

The function that processes the message is synchronous.  How, do I call the RenewLock while the function continues to execute?

Comment: can you renew it before starting long processing? or do you need to keep renewal every 60s?

Comment: I need to keep renewing every 60seconds

Answer (score 1):

For thid kind of scenario OnMessage API provided by the ASB client can help. OnMessage API allows to register a callback and specify a maximum auto lock renewal time so that you don't have to do it yourself.

Here's a detailed explanation on how it works: https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/azure-service-bus-onmessage-api

Answer (score 0):

You have at least few basic options:

1. Start a timer and fire it every 60s or less to renew lock, timer is fired on threadpool so you will not be blocked by your main work
2. Offload heavy lifting to a separate thread and keep main one almost idle, just waiting for conditional variable for 60s or less in a loop, conditional variable should be signaled once job is done